# Ensuring the <section> height matches the viewport height on re-fresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, height, viewport

I am trying to get the height of a `<section>` to match that of the viewport on each page re-load. The `<section>` height then needs to remain at that height, even if the user re-sizes the window viewport.

i.e the viewport is height: 450px, then the  is set to 450px. When the viewport is increased to 465px then the  remains at 450px.

Thanks,

Comment: This? http://jsfiddle.net/Rc3Q6/

Answer (score 1):

Simply use:

```
$('section').height(function(){
    return $(window).height();
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Rc3Q6/1/).

Or,  more simply, use:

```
$('section').height($(window).height());
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Rc3Q6/2/).

This will explicitly set the `height` to the height of the viewport, or at least to the height of the `window`; and, so long as you don't bind to the `resize` event on the viewport, it shouldn't be changed.

Comment: Thanks David - but seems the

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

section {
    background: green;
    height: 100%;
}

is all that is needed.

Comment: It *almost* is, if you hadn't specified 'height then needs to remain at that height, even if the user re-sizes the window viewport,' I wouldn't have bothered to leave a jQuery-based answer. However if you only meant you needed it to fill 100% of the height of the window, CSS works; if you need it to remain 100% of the *original* window, then you'll need a JavaScript solution.